# CIVI Crm Wordpress with Xampp crashes my SQL

Tags: wordpress

I installed CIVIcrm on latest version of wordpress, and appart from PHP version 5 (they recommend 7) it seems like it installed fine, however, it crashes my Sql any idea?

Here are some of the errors , file is too long, so will only paste some of it:

```
DB_Error Object ( [error_message_prefix] => [mode] => 1 [level] => 1024 [code] 
=> -1 [message] => DB Error: unknown error [userinfo] => CREATE TABLE 
`civicrm_participant_status_type` ( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
COMMENT 'unique participant status type id', `name` varchar(64) COMMENT 'non- 
localized name of the status type', `label` varchar(255) COMMENT 'localized 
label for display of this status type', `class` varchar(8) COMMENT 'the general 
group of status type this one belongs to', `is_reserved` tinyint COMMENT 
'whether this is a status type required by the system', `is_active` tinyint 
DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'whether this status type is active', `is_counted` tinyint 
COMMENT 'whether this status type is counted against event size limit', `weight` 
int unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'controls sort order', `visibility_id` int 
unsigned COMMENT 'whether the status type is visible to the public, an implicit 
foreign key to option_value.value related to the `visibility` option_group' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 
utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1813 ** Tablespace for table 
'`wpcivi`.`civicrm_participant_status_type`' exists. Please DISCARD the 
tablespace before IMPORT.] [backtrace] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => 
C:\Core\01-Xampp\htdocs\wpcivi\wp- 
 content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB.php [line] => 985
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have attempted to install this more than once, or maybe run out of diskspace?  The error message above shows:

```
nativecode=1813 ** Tablespace for table '`wpcivi`.`civicrm_participant_status_type`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_tablespace_exists

This looks like it might have some answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: Well, absolutely non related issue caused this my stupid...LastPass password manager kept injecting wrong password in installation field, I disabled the chrome extension, and then it worked fine!